# Facebook Analytics Push Campaigns - In-App notifications - missing NotificationsManager

Tags: android, push-notification, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-analytics

I'm trying to implement FB Analytics Push Campaigns on Android.

Eveything went fine with the push notifications, so I've turned my attention to the in-app notifications.

The [docs' example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/push-campaigns/android) calls for the use of a class called `NotificationsManager`:

```
public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {
  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    if (NotificationsManager.canPresentCard(data)) {
      NotificationsManager.presentNotification(
        this,
        data,
        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't for the life of me find that class in the FB SDK, nor in the FB-Audience SDK.

I'm using v4.17.0 of the SDK. The [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/change-log-4x) states in-app notifications were added on 4.11.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow. FB has the worst docs ever.

Apparently there is a small open source project that handles in-app notifications, and it's separated from the main SDK.

To get NotificationsManager, you need to add the following line to your gradle.build file:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:notifications:1+';
```

Also, here is the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/facebook/FBNotifications) for the notifications project. It contains some samples to help you with the integration.

EDIT: I've alerted FB to the issue and the support rep opened a ticket for them to update the doc.

Comment: Also - in-app notifications seems half-baked on Android. You can't even set the icon for the notifications. I suggest dropping it for now.

Comment: You can use your own icons by providing your own instance of NotificationsManager.NotificationExtender when you call Notificationsmanager.presentNotification(context, data, intent, notificationExtender)